# Quais as diferenças entre utf8 e utf8mb4?

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8

Ao importar o meu banco mysql para um servidor windows após tê-lo criado num servidor local(xampp), não conseguia importar no servidor o script que exportei do banco. Então resolvi ir copiando os scripts de tabela por tabela, e verifiquei que apenas uma parte do script dava erro:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Retirando todas essas ocorrências do script exportado, consegui subir o banco pro servidor windows. Porém alguns problemas estão ocorrendo, como algumas páginas do website que ficam com acentuação trocada pro símbolos e outros problemas que não sei se são decorrentes da ausência da linha supracitada.

Eu queria entender a(s) **diferença(s)** que existe(m) entre o utf8 e o utf8mb4, para ver se isso pode estar ocasionando os problemas do website.

Comment: utf8mb4 permite um byte a mais na codificação, basicamente isso. Pra uso em línguas correntes, utf8mb4 é a mesma coisa que a versão com 3 bytes. Provavelmente seu problema é em outra parte do código.

Comment: mas naquelas linhas em que estão as opções CHARSET e COLLATE, é somente para isso que elas servem, permitir um byte a mais na codificação?

Comment: basicamente não muda nada em lugar nenhum, a não ser ocupar mais espaço no DB quando você definir algo em CHAR. CHAR(10) reserva 30 bytes em utf8, CHAR(10) reserva 40 em utf8mb4, e CHAR(10) reserva 10 bytes em latin. Os caracteres BMP, que são os suportados pelo utf8 são idênticos aos do utf8mb4.

Comment: Ah entendi, então isso não deve ser a causa do problema aqui, manda esse teu comentário como resposta para eu aceitar

Comment: Não prometo, mas se eu pegar algumas referências mais técnicas, depois posto como resposta. Só quis adiantar o assunto pra você ter uma noção básica. Acho que pra resposta, tá faltando por fontes boas pro pessoal consultar (acho que respostas desse tipo merecem uma explicação mais detalhada, então se der eu elaboro melhor depois).

Comment: Beleza, no aguardo.

Comment: Obviamente que se alguém quiser postar uma resposta detalhada, e falando coisa com coisa, sinta-se à vontade (se for pra explicar melhor, senão recomendo deixar só como comentário também. Se for pra falar besteira, o comentário "salva" a pessoa de negativação).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Antigamente as linguagens de programação suportavam apenas a codificação ASCII que define 128 símbolos. Essa codificação é excelente para o inglês, produzindo textos bem compactos onde cada letra gasta apenas um byte. Com o crescimento da internet e um mundo cada vez mais globalizado, rapidamente começaram a surgir problemas, como as pessoas do Brasil não poderem usar acentos em suas palavras.
Foi aí que começaram iniciativas para se criar uma codificação que reunisse todos os símbolos usados pelo mundo inteiro.

O ASCII só define 128 símbolos, o que faz com que o primeiro bit de todo byte seja zero nessa codificação. O padrão UTF-8 aproveitou isso e definiu os primeiros 128 símbolos exatamente iguais ao ASCII. Quando um caractere que não está presente nesse padrão é necessário, o UTF-8 coloca o valor do primeiro bit como 1 e define códigos que dizem se o caractere vai ter 1, 2, 3 ou 4 bytes. Portanto um programa que utilize UTF-8 terá compatibilidade total com qualquer texto em ASCII.

O problema é que o MySQL não aderiu completamente ao padrão UTF-8. Ele implementou apenas símbolos de até 3 bytes e esqueceu o resto. O que se declara no MySQL como utf8 na verdade não é UTF-8, é apenas um pedaço dele. Para consertar este erro, a partir da versão 5.5, o MySQL implementou o padrão completo indo de 1 até 4 bytes e como já havia usado o nome utf8 chamou sua nova implementação de utf8mb4. Resumindo o utf8 do MySQL não é UTF-8 e o utf8mb4 segue totalmente o padrão UTF-8.

Ainda assim, o utf8 e o utf8mb4 tem uma grande compatibilidade, a maioria absoluta dos caracteres vão ser iguais nos dois sistemas. Se você trocar de um para o outro provavelmente não vai ver diferença. A não ser é claro, que pessoas chinesas comecem a usar animais como letras, aí eles vão ficar chateados quando aparecer #û&ý no lugar dos gatinhos. Mesmo que você utilize todos os acentos existentes não daria nenhum problema!

A questão é que, o padrão do MySQL é a codificação Latin1, também conhecida como ISO 8859-1 que define todos os caracteres da língua latina e pode ser muito bem utilizada no português. Quando você deixou de declarar UTF-8mb4, o MySQL utilizou essa codificação e como sua aplicação está provavelmente em UTF-8 esses padrões não representam os acentos da mesma maneira, mas representam ASCII da mesma forma, por isso o erro aparece só nos acentos.

Talvez essa parte do script deu errado pois a versão do MySQL usada não suporta utf8mb4. Se esse for o caso é só utilizar o utf8 no lugar, que os acentos serão compatíveis.

Comment: Em princípio se não usar o 4º byte, o resto dos caracteres é o mesmo. A única coisa que muda além disso é quanto espaço o MySQL reserva pra trabalhar com colunas fixas se for mb4 ou não. Dei meu +1 pela resposta detalhada, em especial pelo "a codificação Latin1, também conhecida como ISO 8859-1 que define todos os caracteres da lingua latina e pode ser muito bem utilizado no português", que tem gente que teima em não entender. E ainda, com a vantagem do ISO-8859-1 gastar 1 byte só por caractere e ser mais rápido de se processar.